# How to remove substring matching to any element of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, string

I have:

```
str ="this is the string "
```

and I have an array of strings:

```
array =["this is" ,"second element", "third element"]
```

I want to process the string such that substring matching any of the element of the array should be removed and rest of the string should be returned. I want the following output:

```
output: "the string "
```

How can i do this?.

Comment: I think you should look into Regex (regular expressions).  They solve exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Define "`sub string matching`". Do you mean true substrings, or do you mean you want to honor word boundaries so that you only match complete words?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't say whether you want true substring matching, or substring matching at word-boundaries. There's a difference. Here's how to do it honoring word boundaries:

```
str = "this is the string "
array = ["this is" ,"second element", "third element"]
pattern = /\b(?:#{ Regexp.union(array).source })\b/ # => /\b(?:this\ is|second\ element|third\ element)\b/

str[pattern] # => "this is"
str.gsub(pattern, '').squeeze(' ').strip # => "the string"
```

Here's what's happening with `union` and `union.source`:

```
Regexp.union(array) # => /this\ is|second\ element|third\ element/
Regexp.union(array).source # => "this\\ is|second\\ element|third\\ element"
```

`source` returns the joined array in a form that can be more easily consumed by Regex when creating a pattern, without it injecting holes into the pattern. Consider these differences and what they could do in a pattern match:

```
/#{ Regexp.union(%w[a . b]) }/ # => /(?-mix:a|\.|b)/
/#{ Regexp.union(%w[a . b]).source }/ # => /a|\.|b/
```

The first creates a separate pattern, with its own flags for case, multiple-line and white-space honoring, that would be embedded inside the outer pattern. That can be a bug that's really hard to track down and fix, so only do it when you intend to have the sub-pattern.

Also, notice what happens if you try to use:

```
/#{ %w[a . b].join('|') }/ # => /a|.|b/
```

The resulting pattern has a wildcard `.` embedded in it, which would blow apart your pattern, causing it to match anything. Don't go there.

If we don't tell the regex engine to honor word boundaries then unexpected/undesirable/terrible things can happen:

```
str = "this isn't the string "
array = ["this is" ,"second element", "third element"]
pattern = /(?:#{ Regexp.union(array).source })/ # => /(?:this\ is|second\ element|third\ element)/

str[pattern] # => "this is"
str.gsub(pattern, '').squeeze(' ').strip # => "n't the string"
```

It's important to think in terms of words, when working with substrings containing complete words. The engine doesn't know the difference, so you have to tell it what to do. This is a situation missed all too often by people who haven't had to do text processing.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way -

```
array =["this is" ,"second element", "third element"]
str = "this is the string "
str.gsub(Regexp.union(array),'') # => " the string "
```

To allow *case-insensitive* - <strike>`str.gsub(/#{array.join('|')}/i,'')`</strike>

Answer (score 0):

I saw two kinds of solutions and at first I prefer Brad's. But I think the two approaches are so different that there must be a performance diff so I created below file and run it.

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

str = 'this is the string '
array =['this is' ,'second element', 'third element']

def by_loop(str, array)
  array.inject(str) { |result , substring| result.gsub substring, ''  }
end

def by_regex(str, array)
  str.gsub(Regexp.union(array),'')
end

def by_loop_large(str, array)
  array = array * 100
  by_loop(str, array)
end

def by_regex_large(str, array)
  array = array * 100
  by_regex(str, array)
end

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report("loop")  { by_loop(str, array) }
  x.report("regex") { by_regex(str, array) }
  x.report("loop large")  { by_loop_large(str, array) }
  x.report("regex large") { by_regex_large(str, array) }
end
```

The result:

```
-------------------------------------------------
            loop    16719.0 (±10.4%) i/s -      83888 in   5.073791s
           regex    18701.5 (±4.2%) i/s -      94554 in   5.063600s
      loop large      182.6 (±0.5%) i/s -        918 in   5.027865s
     regex large      330.9 (±0.6%) i/s -       1680 in   5.076771s
```

The conclusion:

Arup's approach is much more efficient when the array going large.

*As to the Tin Man's concern of single quote in text, I think it's very important but that would be the responsibility of OP but not the current algorithms. And the two approaches produce the same on that string.*