# How to embed regular expressions in other regular expressions in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string:

```
'A Foo'
```

and want to find "Foo" in it.

I have a regular expression:

```
/foo/
```

that I'm embedding into another case-insensitive regular expression, so I can build the pattern in steps:

```
foo_regex = /foo/
pattern = /A #{ foo_regex }/i
```

But it won't match correctly:

```
'A Foo' =~ pattern # => nil
```

If I embed the text directly into the pattern it works:

```
'A Foo' =~ /A foo/i # => 0
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Tin Man gives good advice. Ruby is a Perl wanna-be. As such it compiles every regex with a scoped cluster group construct (such as `(?misx-misx:<your regex>)` ). So this syntax `/ string1 /` compiles a regex with _no options_, and default's to `(?-misx:string 1)` Another regex `/ string2 /i` compiled with the `i` flag, adds it to the plus side `(?i-msx: string 2 )`. Since cluster groups are _scoped_ the options _inside_ the cluster take precedence. So, regex 1 inside regex 2 is `(?i-msx: string 2 (?-misx: string 1))` and of course scope dictates `string 1` is now case sensitive.

Comment: I wouldn't say Ruby is a Perl wanna-be. It's more like Java, Perl and some other languages blended their parts and came up with Ruby.

Comment: Sort of like .. master of none

Comment: LOL, as if you didn't know "what's wrong" ;)

Comment: @theTinMan: Perl, Smalltalk or Lisp, yes. But Java? I really don't see many similarities.

Answer (score 10):

On the surface it seems that embedding a pattern inside another pattern would simply work, but that's based on a bad assumption of how patterns work in Ruby, that they're simply strings. Using:

```
foo_regex = /foo/
```

creates a Regexp object:

```
/foo/.class # => Regexp
```

As such it has knowledge of the optional flags used to create it:

```
( /foo/    ).options # => 0
( /foo/i   ).options # => 1
( /foo/x   ).options # => 2
( /foo/ix  ).options # => 3
( /foo/m   ).options # => 4
( /foo/im  ).options # => 5
( /foo/mx  ).options # => 6
( /foo/imx ).options # => 7
```

or, if you like binary:

```
'%04b' % ( /foo/    ).options # => "0000"
'%04b' % ( /foo/i   ).options # => "0001"
'%04b' % ( /foo/x   ).options # => "0010"
'%04b' % ( /foo/xi  ).options # => "0011"
'%04b' % ( /foo/m   ).options # => "0100"
'%04b' % ( /foo/mi  ).options # => "0101"
'%04b' % ( /foo/mx  ).options # => "0110"
'%04b' % ( /foo/mxi ).options # => "0111"
```

and remembers those whenever the Regexp is used, whether as a standalone pattern or if embedded in another.

You can see this in action if we look to see what the pattern looks like after embedding:

```
/#{ /foo/  }/ # => /(?-mix:foo)/
/#{ /foo/i }/ # => /(?i-mx:foo)/
```

`?-mix:` and `?i-mx:` are how those options are represented in an embedded-pattern.

According to the Regexp documentation for [Options](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Options):

> `i`, `m`, and `x` can also be applied on the subexpression level with the *(?on-off)* construct, which enables options *on*, and disables options *off* for the expression enclosed by the parentheses.

So, Regexp is remembering those options, even inside the outer pattern, causing the overall pattern to fail the match:

```
pattern = /A #{ foo_regex }/i # => /A (?-mix:foo)/i
'A Foo' =~ pattern # => nil
```

It's possible to make sure that all sub-expressions match their surrounding patterns, however that can quickly become too convoluted or messy:

```
foo_regex = /foo/i
pattern = /A #{ foo_regex }/i # => /A (?i-mx:foo)/i
'A Foo' =~ pattern # => 0
```

Instead we have the `source` method which returns the text of a pattern:

```
/#{ /foo/.source  }/ # => /foo/
/#{ /foo/i.source }/ # => /foo/
```

The problem with the embedded pattern remembering the options also appears when using other Regexp methods, such as `union`:

```
/#{ Regexp.union(%w[a b]) }/ # => /(?-mix:a|b)/
```

and again, `source` can help:

```
/#{ Regexp.union(%w[a b]).source }/ # => /a|b/
```

Knowing all that:

```
foo_regex = /foo/
pattern = /#{ foo_regex.source }/i # => /foo/i
'A Foo' =~ pattern # => 2
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42729953/128421, http://stackoverflow.com/a/16705515/128421, http://stackoverflow.com/a/23701327/128421 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/38154742/128421 for additional information about this.

Comment: Now I know which answer I'll link to ;)

Answer (score 2):

> *"what's wrong?"*

Your assumption on how a `Regexp` is interpolated is wrong.

Interpolation via `#{...}` is done by calling `to_s` on the interpolated object:

```
d = Date.new(2017, 9, 8)
#=> #<Date: 2017-09-08 ((2458005j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

d.to_s
#=> "2017-09-08"

"today is #{d}!"
#=> "today is 2017-09-08!"
```

and not just for string literals, but also for regular expression literals:

```
/today is #{d}!/
#=> /today is 2017-09-08!/
```

In your example, the object-to-be-interpolated is a `Regexp`:

```
foo_regex = /foo/
```

And [`Regexp#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Regexp.html#method-i-to_s) returns:

> [...] the regular expression and its options using the **(?opts:source)** notation.

```
foo_regex.to_s
#=> "(?-mix:foo)"
```

Therefore:

```
/A #{foo_regex}/i
#=> /A (?-mix:foo)/i
```

Just like:

```
"A #{foo_regex}"
#=> "A (?-mix:foo)"
```

In other words: because of the way `Regexp#to_s` is implemented, you can interpolate patterns without loosing their flags. It's a feature, not a bug.

If `Regexp#to_s` would return just the source (without options), it would work the way you expect:

```
def foo_regex.to_s
  source
end

/A #{foo_regex}/i
#=> /A foo/i
```

The above code is just for demonstration purposes, don't do that.